# Neural network hidden layer vs. Convolutional hidden layer intuition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

If there are 10 features and 1 output class (sigmoid activation) with a regression objective:

If I use only 5 neurons in my first dense hidden layer: will the first error be calculated solely based on half of the training feature set? Isn't it imperative to match the # of features with the neurons in hidden layer #1 so that the model can see all the features at once? Otherwise it's not getting the whole picture? The first fwd propagation iteration would use 5 out of 10 features, and get the error value (and train during backprop, assume batch grad descent). Then the 2nd fwd propagation iteration would see the remaining 5 out of 10 features with updated weights and hopefully arrive at a smaller error. BUT its only seeing half the features at a time!

Conversely, if I have a convolutional 2D layer of 64 neurons. And my training shape is: (100, 28,28,1) (pictures of cats and dogs in greyscale), will each of the 64 neurons see a different 28x28 vector? No right, because it can only send one example through the forward propagation at a time? So then only a single picture (cat or dog) should be spanned across the 64 neurons? Why would you want that since each neuron in that layer has the same filter, stride, padding and activation function? When you define a Conv2D layer...the parameters of each neuron are the same. So is only a part of the training example going into each neuron? Why have 64 neurons, for example? Just have one neuron, use a filter on it and pass it along to a second hidden layer with another filter with different parameters!

Please explain the flaws in my logic. Thanks so much.

EDIT: I just realized for Conv2D, you flatten the training data sets so it becomes a 1D vector and so a 28x28 image would mean having an input conv2d layer of 724 neurons. But I am still confused for the dense neural network (paragraph #1 above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your "first" layer?
Normally you have an input layer as first layer, which does not contain any weights.
The shape of the input layer **must** match the shape of your feature data.
So basically when you train a model with 10 features, but only have a input layer of shape `(None,5)` (where none stands for the batch_size), tensorflow will raise an exception, because it needs data for **all** inputs in the correct shape.

So what you said is just not going to happen. If you only have 5 features, the next 5 features wont be fit into the net in the next iteration **but**, the next sample will be send to the model instead. (Lets say no exception is thrown) So of the next sample also **only** the first 5 features would be used.

What you can do instead, use a `input_layer` as first layer with the correct shape of your features. Then as secodn layer, you can use any shape you like, 1,10,100 dense neurons, its up to you (and what works well of course). **The shape of the output** again must match (this time) the shape of your label data.

I hope this makes it more clear